# Как просуммировать значения по группам в запросе

Tags: mysql, sql

Доброго времени суток.
Есть массив полученный из бд MySQL по SQL SELECT.
Изначально он имеет такой вид:

id - id прогноза
seller_id - id seller(а)
customer_id - id customer(a)
product_id - id продукта
quantity - количество заказанных едениц продукта
forecast - сумма заказа
date - дата когда был сделан прогноз (понедельник каждого месяца)

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [seller_id] => 36
            [customer_id] => 7
            [product_id] => 1
            [quantity] => 10
            [forecast] => 50
            [date] => 2016-11-07
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 2
            [seller_id] => 36
            [customer_id] => 7
            [product_id] => 1
            [quantity] => 11
            [forecast] => 60
            [date] => 2016-11-14
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [id] => 3
            [seller_id] => 35
            [customer_id] => 6
            [product_id] => 2
            [quantity] => 5
            [forecast] => 25
            [date] => 2016-11-07
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [id] => 3
            [seller_id] => 35
            [customer_id] => 6
            [product_id] => 2
            [quantity] => 2
            [forecast] => 10
            [date] => 2016-11-14
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [id] => 3
            [seller_id] => 35
            [customer_id] => 6
            [product_id] => 3
            [quantity] => 5
            [forecast] => 25
            [date] => 2016-11-07
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [id] => 3
            [seller_id] => 35
            [customer_id] => 6
            [product_id] => 3
            [quantity] => 2
            [forecast] => 10
            [date] => 2016-11-14
        )

)
```

Нужно отсортировать его по seller_id, customer_id, product_id, в случае если product_id, seller_id, customer_id совпадают, сложить quantity с quantity и forecast c forecast совпавшего массива.

Данный массив это список прогнозов пользователей за 2 недели (каждая неделя отдельно), а нужно привести к виду когда мы объединили результаты первой и второй недели.

После должен иметь такой вид:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [seller_id] => 36
            [customer_id] => 7
            [product_id] => 1
            [quantity] => 21
            [forecast] => 110
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [seller_id] => 35
            [customer_id] => 6
            [product_id] => 2
            [quantity] => 7
            [forecast] => 35
        )
    [2] => Array
        (
            [seller_id] => 35
            [customer_id] => 6
            [product_id] => 3
            [quantity] => 2
            [forecast] => 10

        )

)
```

Жду вашей помощи, не судите строго я front-end и приходится выполнить задачу на php, направьте меня или помогите с алгоритмом. Сортировка в дальнейшем будет сортировать: 2 недели, 3 недели, месяц, 2 месяца, 3 месяца, 4 месяца.
Заранее спасибо!

Comment: А вы уверены, что это надо делать в php ? SQL способен отдать данные в том виде, в котором они нужны клиенту и выполнить на своей стороне это суммирование и группировку

Comment: Я тоже в эту сторону думал, можно пример? Большое спасибо за то что откликнулись!

Comment: google: "mysql group by sum"

Comment: Большое спасибо, сейчас буду разбираться!

Comment: в вашем случае что то типа `select ..., sum(quantity), sum(forecast) from table group by  product_id, seller_id, customer_id`

Comment: Большое спасибо, я разобрался и за пример благодарю!!! Хорошего дня!

Comment: SELECT  products.name product, customers.customer, sum(forecasts.forecast), sum(forecasts.quantity), forecasts.start_date
FROM forecasts
LEFT JOIN products ON products.id = forecasts.product_id
LEFT JOIN customers ON customers.id = forecasts.customer_id
WHERE forecasts.seller_id = "36" AND forecasts.start_date IN ("2016-11-07","2016-11-14", "2016-11-21")
GROUP BY forecasts.product_id, forecasts.customer_id, forecasts.seller_id

Comment: Получилось вот так, еще раз спасибо! Вопрос решен!

Comment: Если вопрос решен - напишите ответ и заапрувьте его.

Comment: Помогите пожалуйста столбец region из row перенести в col (поместить в него значение forecast и region со значением quantity) при этом учитывая что регионов может быть любое кол-во, буду очень благодарен за полезные статьи. Если не сложно прокомментируйте, так как у меня пока что еще ничего не получается.

Comment: Mike, Вас не затруднит если я задам вам еще 1 вопрос?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
SELECT products.name product,
       products.price,
       regions.region,
       SUM(forecasts.quantity) AS quantity,
       SUM(forecasts.forecast) AS forecast,
       forecasts.start_date
FROM forecasts
     LEFT JOIN products ON products.id = forecasts.product_id
     LEFT JOIN regions ON regions.id = forecasts.region_id
WHERE forecasts.start_date = "2016-11-14"
GROUP BY forecasts.product_id,
         forecasts.region_id;
```